# iOS Why are my UIPickerview methods looping?

Tags: ios, loops, core-data, uipickerview

I built what I thought would be a simple program to explore the issue of CoreData relationships.

However, these two methods are unexpectedly looping after a segue (and arriving successfully at the destination `VC`). The methods involved are `numberOfRowsInComponent` (loops `4` times) and `titleForRow` (loops `5` times), creating this `NSLog` output before continuing:

```
2014-03-01 12:12:26.231 EntitiesAndRelationships[64785:a0b] Number of categories is 2
2014-03-01 12:12:26.233 EntitiesAndRelationships[64785:a0b] Number of categories is 2
2014-03-01 12:12:26.236 EntitiesAndRelationships[64785:a0b] Number of categories is 2
2014-03-01 12:12:26.237 EntitiesAndRelationships[64785:a0b] Number of categories is 2
2014-03-01 12:12:26.239 EntitiesAndRelationships[64785:a0b] Description of row is <WMDGCategory: 0x8a8a420> (entity: WMDGCategory; id: 0x8a8e2c0 <x-coredata://75EA0FB2-AB3F-480A-9EBE-CDA14EDEB902/WMDGCategory/p2> ; data: <fault>)
2014-03-01 12:12:26.242 EntitiesAndRelationships[64785:a0b] Description of row is <WMDGCategory: 0x8a8c110> (entity: WMDGCategory; id: 0x8a8e2d0 <x-coredata://75EA0FB2-AB3F-480A-9EBE-CDA14EDEB902/WMDGCategory/p1> ; data: <fault>)
2014-03-01 12:12:26.246 EntitiesAndRelationships[64785:a0b] Description of row is <WMDGCategory: 0x8a8a420> (entity: WMDGCategory; id: 0x8a8e2c0 <x-coredata://75EA0FB2-AB3F-480A-9EBE-CDA14EDEB902/WMDGCategory/p2> ; data: <fault>)
2014-03-01 12:12:26.247 EntitiesAndRelationships[64785:a0b] Description of row is <WMDGCategory: 0x8a8c110> (entity: WMDGCategory; id: 0x8a8e2d0 <x-coredata://75EA0FB2-AB3F-480A-9EBE-CDA14EDEB902/WMDGCategory/p1> ; data: <fault>)
2014-03-01 12:12:26.249 EntitiesAndRelationships[64785:a0b] Description of row is <WMDGCategory: 0x8a8a420> (entity: WMDGCategory; id: 0x8a8e2c0 <x-coredata://75EA0FB2-AB3F-480A-9EBE-CDA14EDEB902/WMDGCategory/p2> ; data: <fault>)
```

Here's the code for the two methods:

```
- (NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
    frc = [WMDGCategory MR_fetchAllGroupedBy:nil withPredicate:nil sortedBy:@"name" ascending:YES];
    NSInteger *catCount;
    catCount = frc.fetchedObjects.count;
    NSLog(@"Number of categories is %zd", catCount);
    return frc.fetchedObjects.count;
}

#pragma mark Picker View delegate

- (NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component;
{
    NSString * description;
    description = [[frc.fetchedObjects objectAtIndex:row]description];
    NSLog(@"Description of row is %@", description);
    return [[frc.fetchedObjects objectAtIndex:row]description];
}
```

I'm pretty puzzled. Can someone help, please?

Thanks!

**Edit per reecon's answer below**

I moved this line:

```
frc = [WMDGCategory MR_fetchAllGroupedBy:nil withPredicate:nil sortedBy:@"name" ascending:YES];
```

into `viewDidLoad`, but the looping persists.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your data source and delegate methods can get called any number of times - that is not a problem.

You should assume that methods:

```
- (NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component;
```

or

```
- (NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component;
```

can be called at any time and several times. Thus the implementation of it should be lightweight. Move the fetching code elsewhere - e.g. to `viewDidLoad`. So you only fetch once. Then when the picker requests information from its delegate, it does not result in performing a not needed fetch.

Comment: Your data source and delegate methods can get called any number of times - that is not a problem. Is your code working correctly otherwise?

Comment: Yes, so far, so good. I still have stuff to implement, but I got hung up by that little quirk. Many thanks for setting me straight, but don't be surprised if you hear from me again! :)

Comment: No problem mate :) I'm here to help. Can you accept and upvote my answer if it helped? :)